# Alt+S moves vertex instead of scaling skin modifier in 2.79

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I seem to be having an issue with Alt/S when using the skin modifier. It used to work fine in earlier version, but now it will only move the vertex up or down, it does not scale the skin. I have checked all my shortcuts and nothing has been changed and I have checked the XYZ checkboxes and no effect. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct shortcut to shrink/fatten when using the skin modifier is ctrl-A. I have always wondered why, but that is it.

Comment: Nah, I went through that awhile back - I always thought it should have been alt-s as well.